# Add multiple axes from different sources into same figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using Python/matplotlib to create a figure whereby it has three subplots, each returned from a different 'source' or class method.

For example, I have a script called 'plot_spectra.py' that contains the `Spectra()` class with method `Plot()`.

So, calling Spectra('filename.ext').Plot() will return a tuple, as per the code below:

```
# create the plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.contour(xx, yy, plane, levels=cl, cmap=cmap)
ax.set_xlim(ppm_1h_0, ppm_1h_1)
ax.set_ylim(ppm_13c_0, ppm_13c_1)

# return the contour plot
return fig, ax
```

It is my understanding that the 'figure' is the 'window' in matplotlib, and the 'ax' is an individual plot. I would then want to say, plot three of these 'ax' objects in the same figure, but I am struggling to do so because I keep getting an empty window and I think I have misunderstood what each object actually is.

Calling:

```
hnca, hnca_ax = Spectra('data/HNCA.ucsf', type='sparky').Plot(plane_ppm=resi.N(), vline=resi.H())
plt.subplot(2,2,1)
plt.subplot(hnca_ax)

eucplot, barplot = PlotEucXYIntensity(scores, x='H', y='N')

plt.subplot(2,2,3)
plt.subplot(eucplot)

plt.subplot(2,2,4)
plt.subplot(barplot)

plt.show()
```

Ultimately, what I am trying to obtain is a single window that looks like this:

[image]

Where each plot has been returned from a different function or class method.

**What 'object' do I need to return from my functions? And how do I incorporate these three objects into a single figure?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest this kind of approach, where you specify the ax on which you want to plot in the function:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

def Spectra(data, ax):
  ax.plot(data)

def PlotIntensity(data, ax):
  ax.hist(data)

def SeabornScatter(data, ax):
  sns.scatterplot(data, data, ax = ax)

spectrum = np.random.random((1000,))

plt.figure()

ax1 = plt.subplot(1,3,1)
Spectra(spectrum, ax1)

ax2 = plt.subplot(1,3,2)
SeabornScatter(spectrum, ax2)

ax3 = plt.subplot(1,3,3)
PlotIntensity(spectrum, ax3)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

You can specify the grid for the subplots in very different ways, and you probably also want to have a look on the [`gridspec`](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html) module.

Comment: I like this way of doing it -- but am I able to still use seaborn to draw my graphs this way? How do I draw with seaborn in this case? I dont think I can call ax2.scatterplot() for example

Comment: `seaborn` plot functions have an optional argument where you can precise the zx you want to plot on. See my edited answer. Otherwise you can use matplotlib scatterplot function :)

Comment: You're a living legend. :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is:

```
f = plt.figure()
gs = f.add_gridspec(2,2)
ax = f.add_subplot(gs[0,:])
```

Think of the '2,2' as adding 2 row x 2 columns.
On the third line 'gs[0,:]' is telling to add a chart on row 0, all columns. This will create the chart on the top of your top. Note that indices begin with 0 and not with 1.

To add the 'eucplot' you will have to call a different ax on row 1 and column 0:

```
ax2 = f.add_subplot(gs[1,0])
```

Lastly, the 'barplot' will go in yet a different ax on row 1, column 1:

```
ax3 = f.add_subplot(gs[1,1])
```

See this site here for further reference: [Customizing Figure Layouts Using GridSpec and Other Functions](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html)

Comment: Thank you for the gridspec info!